# Gettext issue with Nginx, PHP and Docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, gettext

I am currently switching from Apache to Nginx in a project where I'm also setting up Docker. However, it seems that I am having trouble making Gettext picking up translations correctly.

I have one Nginx container and one PHP (fpm) container which are working properly together.

Gettext has been installed in the PHP container and the extension shows up as enabled and is available in the code.

The relevant locale ("sv-SE") has been installed in the PHP container. Running "Locale -a" returns the following:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
sv_SE
sv_SE.iso88591
sv_SE.iso885915
sv_SE.utf8
swedish
```

Testing code for Gettext:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
textdomain('main');
bindtextdomain('main', LOCALE_PATH);
bindtextdomain('urls', LOCALE_PATH);
bind_textdomain_codeset('main', 'UTF-8');
echo gettext("Yes");
```

$locale = "sv-SE" and LOCALE_PATH is simply the path to the translations in the Nginx container and appears to be picked up correctly.

I really don't understand what the issue is here but the text is not translated and there are no error messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: The code "works" as such in the sense that there are no error messages but the text is not translated as it is in the previous Apache environment. At first I had an issue with the locale being different but now I have no idea where the issue lies but I am thinking I'm missing something with Nginx or the container.